# Right way to architect two paths for adding users

Tags: ember.js

Right now I have the following app - http://jsbin.com/okoxim/7/edit

It allows a person to browse users by name or by class. If browsing by users, and you click new user, you get new form with no default values, and upon save you get directed to that user details.

When browsing by class I want to give the option to add a new user and the new form should default to the current class that was on when the new user option was selected and upon save, we should route back to the class that was saved.

What is the right way to setup my routes to facilitate this scenario and how should I reuse my existing new controller for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom `event` to manage this from inside your route. From your view/controller you bubble up the event to the route, which takes care of adding the student given some data.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  events: {
    createStudent: function(student, gradeId) {
      var grade = App.Grade.find(gradeId);
      var newStudent = App.Student.create({
        name: student.name,
        address: student.address,
        grade: grade
      }); 

      newStudent.save();
      // other application related stuff
    }
  }
});
```

And from the controller you use `send` to dispatch an event with this data to the route.

```
save: function() {
  var gradeId = this.get('newGrade');
  var student = {
    name: this.get('newName'),
    address: this.get('newAddress')
  };
  this.send('createStudent', student, gradeId);
  // other view related stuff
}
```

The `createStudent` event can then be reused from different controllers/views.

Comment: So, create routes/controllers for each path and let the create Student be the one thing that is shared?

Comment: Yes. Also note that events bubble, up to the ApplicationController, giving the opportunity to define/customize the `createStudent` event on route before they reach the top level Route.